# Fixed point multiplication of negative numbers

Tags: fixed-point

I have the following method to multiply two 32 bit numbers in fixed point
`19.13` format. But I think there is a problem with this method:

`1.5f` is rounded up to `2.0f`, while `-1.5f` is rounded up to `-1.0f`.

It seems to me that `-1.5` should be rounded down to `-2.0f`.

First, does the current rounding make sense, and if not, how can I change it 
to be more consistent?

```
static OPJ_INT32 opj_int_fix_mul(OPJ_INT32 a, OPJ_INT32 b) {
    OPJ_INT64 temp = (OPJ_INT64) a * (OPJ_INT64) b ;
   temp += 4096;
   assert((temp >> 13) <= (OPJ_INT64)0x7FFFFFFF);
   assert((temp >> 13) >= (-(OPJ_INT64)0x7FFFFFFF - (OPJ_INT64)1));
   return (OPJ_INT32) (temp >> 13);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are always adding `4096`, code is doing rounding half-way cases toward positive infinity.  It is kind of odd.

To round toward positive  infinity, I'd expect

```
temp += 4096 + 4095;
```

To round in the usual fashion (to nearest), use instead add a bias away from 0.

```
temp += (temp < 0) ? -4096 : 4096;
```

To round to nearest and *ties* to even is more work.  Not certain OP desires that.